# Populating UITableView with an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a array. The array is data from a website. I have to strip some stuff from it and process it (basically company info that I strip down to just one of each state).

The `allStatesFinalArray` is the array I want to show up on the table view.  I can log it just fine in the fetchedData statement. But cannot get it into a tableview. I get several null response in the log from the table view log. Why? I know I am missing something. Please help.

```
//
//  StateTableViewController.m
//

#define kBgQueue            dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sensored.com"] //2

#import "StateTableViewController.h"
#import "ResViewController.h"

@interface StateTableViewController()
@end


@implementation StateTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

}

////new code???
NSArray *allStatesFinalArray;

- (NSArray *)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    //parse out the json data
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSArray *getCompaniesArray = [json objectForKey:@"CompaniesCD"]; //2  get all company info
    NSArray *getStatesArray = [getCompaniesArray valueForKey:@"state"];//get only states
    NSSet *getOneStateSet = [NSSet setWithArray:getStatesArray];//get rid of duplicates
    NSArray* allStatesFinalArray= [getOneStateSet allObjects];//nsset to array

    NSLog(@"allstatesfinalarray log 1  : %@", allStatesFinalArray);//return allStatesFinalArray;

    return allStatesFinalArray;// return an array of just one state

}
////end newcode???


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return 0;

    NSLog(@"allstatesfinalarray log 2  : %@", allStatesFinalArray);//return allStatesFinalArray;

    return [allStatesFinalArray count];
}
////NOTE ABOVE LOG RETURNS CORRECTLY!!!!

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get log after this step   of the array
    NSLog(@"here is the list going to tableview: %@", allStatesFinalArray);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"stateCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [allStatesFinalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
//////NOTE ABOVE LOG RETURNS SEVERAL NILLS????????

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why have you initialized another `allStatesFinalArray` inside `fetchedData:`?

Comment: oh I tried to get any result from fetched data, but does not return anything.  Only allstatesfinalarray does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a confused mess. You have a variable declared between 2 methods:

```
////new code???
NSArray* allStatesFinalArray;
```

That makes it an application global variable, which is bad.

You have 2 variables called `allStatesFinalArray`; an application global, which should be an instance variable, and a local variable inside fetchData that should not exist at all.

Move that variable declaration to the header for your view controller class:

```
@interface StateTableViewController()
{
  NSArray* allStatesFinalArray;
}
@end
```

That makes it an instance variable.

Now change the fetchData method to not return a result:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
```

Also, get rid of the decoration of a local variable `allStatesFinalArray` inside `fetchData`. Have the `fetchData` method save it's results into the `allStatesFinalArray` instance variable.

Now, as the last line of your `fetchData` method, call your table view's `reloadData` method.

Comment: Thank you vary much.  Yes that does work.  I knew i just had a mess to fix.   It is a little slow to get to the refresh or reload the data.   And wired the lines don't show up on table view.  I am sure i can fix those two little issues.  Thanks